# Degrees of freedom for injective endofunctor keeping objects constant?

Tags: category-theory, functors

Suppose we have a category $C$ with at least 2 objects. In fact, I have in mind the category **Set**, but my question applies to all categories.

Suppose we define a functor $F:C\to C$ that

1. Maps objects to themselves: $F_o(X)=X$
2. Is **injective *in endomorphisms*:** for all $f,g:X\to X$ we need $F_m(f)=F_m(g)\implies f=g$.

**How many degrees of freedom do we have for defining such a functor?**

My current conjecture is: Our space of such functors is exactly categorized by:

1. For each object $X$, there has to be a monoid isomorphism between $\text {Hom}(X,X)$ and $F[\text{Hom}(X,X)]$.
2. For each object $X$, we are allowed to choose exactly one isomorphism $\pi_X:X\to X$, so that for all objects $Y\neq X$ and morphisms $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ we have $F(f)=\pi_Y^{-1}\circ f\circ \pi_X$, and $F(g)=\pi_X^{-1}\circ g\circ \pi_Y$.

**Is this correct?**

I also want to think about how the degrees of freedom change if we relax the assumption that objects are mapped to themselves, but keep the assumption that the functor is injective.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Is that solved by requiring that $Y\neq X$? Because that’s what I meant. (Edited)

Comment: In any case, it looks like your construction gives a functor naturally isomorphic to the identity functor, but in general there could very well be functors that are the identity on objects but not isomorphic to the identity functor (I don't know about the category of sets though).

Comment: If $C$ doesn't have many endomorphisms, your condition can become vacuous. For instance there's a category on two objects with only identity endomorphisms, no maps $y$ to $x$, and an arbitrary set $S$ of maps $x$ to $y$. So in this situation you have $S$ degrees of freedom. This example also shows there's no reason to assume there are any choices of isomorphism involved anywhere.

Comment: @ Arnaud D, "Then for good measure you should also say how $F$ acts on maps $X→X$ and $Y→Z$". I think my definition does that now (I've edited). Note that the definition says "for all $X$", so the situation $Y\neq X\neq Z$ doesn't make much sense I think).

Comment: @ArnaudD., "in general there could very well be functors that are the identity on objects but not isomorphic to the identity functor" Is that still the case if we require injectivity on endomorphisms though?

Comment: @user56834 Yes. See Kevin's example.

Comment: In the case of $Set$, if you look at the image of $\hom (1, X)\to \hom (1,X)$ induced by $F$, you see that your kind of functor is very closely related to subfunctors of $Id$ and retractions onto them. In the general case, as Kevin's example shows, we don't have that much information.